# Bootstrap: want to change distance between 2 elements in a Dropdown Navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, list, margin, distance

in the lower Navbar[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8nZl.png) (the red one) you can see two list-elements. I'd like to have lower distance between the Glyphicon and the Caret. and bigger distance between the caret and the next Glyphicon. (but it should be able to change whitz the screen size to a lower distance again)

Can anyone help with the problem? :)

Thank!

```css
body {          background-color: #EFF3F4;
                color: #6a6c6f;
}

a {             color: #6a6c6f; 
                text-decoration: none;}

a:active {}

a:hover {       color: #6a6c6f; 
                text-decoration: none;}

a:link {}

a:visited {}







    
    
adding-bottom: 0px;                        
                        padding-right: auto;
                        margin-top: 0px;
                        margin-bottom: 20px;
                        position: fixed;
                        top: 50px;
                        right: 0px;
                        left: 0px;
                        z-index: 1030;                        
                        background-color: #ff5b5b; 
                        border: 0px;
}
    
    ul.dropdown {       padding: 12.5px;
                        margin: 0px;
                        float: left;
    }
    li.dropdown {       display: inline-block;
    }
    
    
    a.navi-unten {      display: inline-block;
                        color: #fff;
                        text-decoration: none;                    
    }
    a.navi-unten:hover {color: #6a6c6f;
                        text-decoration: none;
    }
    a.navi-unten:focus {color: #6a6c6f;
                        text-decoration: none;
    }





.main {             min-height: 3000px; 
                    padding: 65px 0px 0px 0px; }

div.jumbotron {     margin-top: 100px;
                    background-color: ; }
```

```html
 <body>

      

            
        <!-- START: NAVBAR_oben  --> 
                
        
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
 
  <div class="container">
  
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>   
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><?= $language['phrases']['site_title']; ?></a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#"><span style="font-size:1.25em;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> </a></li>
      </ul>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
        
        <!-- END: NAVBAR_oben -->
               
        <!-- START: NAVBAR_unten -->
        
 <nav class="nav navbar-nav nav-sidebar">
  <div class="container">
     
     <ul class="dropdown">  

<li class="dropdown">
  <a class="navi-unten" id="dLabel" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><span style="font-size:1.5em;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
                        <span class="caret"></span></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
    <li role="presentation"><a class="navi-unten" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Advertiser</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a class="navi-unten" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Kampagnen</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a class="navi-unten" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Listen</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a class="navi-unten" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Jobs</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a class="navi-unten" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Nodes</a></li>
    
  </ul>
</li>
        
<li class="dropdown">
  <a class="navi-unten" id="dLabel" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><span style="font-size:1.5em;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
                        <span class="caret"></span></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
    <li role="presentation"><a class="navi-unten" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Konfigurationen</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a class="navi-unten" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Module</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a class="navi-unten" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Seiten</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a class="navi-unten" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Navigation</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a class="navi-unten" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Gruppen</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a class="navi-unten" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Benutzer</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a class="navi-unten" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Sprachen</a></li>
  </ul>
</li> 


</ul>
  </div>
</nav>        
        
            
                
            
                   
             
          
            
    
        
        
        
        <!-- END: NAVBAR_unten -->

        

        <!-- START: CONTENT -->
        
        
        <div class="container">
           
                <div class="jumbotron">
                   <?php create_element_content($language,$system); ?>
                </div>
              
        </div>
        
        <!-- END: CONTENT -->

    </body>
```

[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCbBB.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
give id to the caret span and pull it right in css and give the id to next glyphicon and pull it left in css....i gave them id1 and id2 in css ..you can adjust in css accordingly 





    body {          background-color: #EFF3F4;
                    color: #6a6c6f;
    }

    a {             color: #6a6c6f; 
                    text-decoration: none;}

    a:active {}

    a:hover {       color: #6a6c6f; 
                    text-decoration: none;}

    a:link {}

    a:visited {}







        
        
    adding-bottom: 0px;                        
                            padding-right: auto;
                            margin-top: 0px;
                            margin-bottom: 20px;
                            position: fixed;
                            top: 50px;
                            right: 0px;
                            left: 0px;
                            z-index: 1030;                        
                            background-color: #ff5b5b; 
                            border: 0px;
    }
        
        ul.dropdown {       padding: 12.5px;
                            margin: 0px;
                            float: left;
        }
        li.dropdown {       display: inline-block;
        }
        
        
        a.navi-unten {      display: inline-block;
                            color: #fff;
                            text-decoration: none;                    
        }
        a.navi-unten:hover {color: #6a6c6f;
                            text-decoration: none;
        }
        a.navi-unten:focus {color: #6a6c6f;
                            text-decoration: none;
        }



 #id1{
margin-right:10px;

}
#id2{
margin-left:10px;
}

    .main {             min-height: 3000px; 
                        padding: 65px 0px 0px 0px; }

    div.jumbotron {     margin-top: 100px;
                        background-color: ; }
     <body>

          

                
            <!-- START: NAVBAR_oben  --> 
                    
            
     <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
     
      <div class="container">
      
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>   
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><?= $language['phrases']['site_title']; ?></a>
        </div>
        
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
          
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li><a href="#"><span style="font-size:1.25em;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> </a></li>
          </ul>
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
            
            <!-- END: NAVBAR_oben -->
                   
            <!-- START: NAVBAR_unten -->
            
     <nav class="nav navbar-nav nav-sidebar">
      <div class="container">
         
         <ul class="dropdown">  

    <li class="dropdown">
      <a class="navi-unten" id="dLabel" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><span style="font-size:1.5em;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
                            <span class="caret" id="id1"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
        <li role="presentation"><a class="navi-unten" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Advertiser</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a class="navi-unten" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Kampagnen</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a class="navi-unten" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Listen</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a class="navi-unten" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Jobs</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a class="navi-unten" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Nodes</a></li>
        
      </ul>
    </li>
            
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a class="navi-unten" id="dLabe1" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><span style="font-size:1.5em;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" id="id2"></span>
                            <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
        <li role="presentation"><a class="navi-unten" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Konfigurationen</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a class="navi-unten" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Module</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a class="navi-unten" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Seiten</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a class="navi-unten" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Navigation</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a class="navi-unten" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Gruppen</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a class="navi-unten" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Benutzer</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a class="navi-unten" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Sprachen</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li> 


    </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>        
            
                
                    
                
                       
                 
              
                
        
            
            
            
            <!-- END: NAVBAR_unten -->

            

            <!-- START: CONTENT -->
            
            
            <div class="container">
               
                    <div class="jumbotron">
                       <?php create_element_content($language,$system); ?>
                    </div>
                  
            </div>
            
            <!-- END: CONTENT -->

        </body>
```